# Retrieve raw data from html.Node

Tags: go

I want to get contents of `html.Node` as a string.

Example:

```
<div id="my-node">
  <p>First paragraph</p>
  <p>Second paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Given `myNode := html.Node("#my-node")` (pseudocode), I want to retrieve entire above html as a string. Indentation does not matter.

I couldn't find anything on the internet except iterating over contents of node - `myNode.NextSibling` but its over complicated and I'm pretty sure there has to be easier way.

Update:
I'm reffering to `golang.org/x/net/html` package.

Comment: That's not from the standard like library as far as I can tell. Which html package are you referring to?

Comment: I don't see how iterating through the tree is "over complicated".  But if you're looking for an alternative, how about rendering to an io.Writer and getting your string from that?

Comment: I'm go beginner, coming from PHP, JS background makes me think that iteration would be over complicated. Maybe `io.Writer` might do the job and be somewhat less complex. I'll try it out.

Comment: Doesn't html.Render do what you want? For instance, give it a *bytes.Buffer, then call *Buffer.String.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get what you mean, I use a lot of this in tests.

What you need is already in the same `x/net/html` package - you can [`Render`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/html#Render) the `Node` to a `bytes.Buffer` then get a string out of it:

```
var b bytes.Buffer
err := html.Render(&b, node)
return b.String()
```

Please read 
[the doc](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/html#Render) 
how rendering is done on the best effort basis - but it will probably fit you.

PS. You can consult how it's used in a more real project of mine:
https://github.com/wkhere/htmlx/blob/f22d01b/finder.go#L32-L39
https://github.com/wkhere/htmlx/blob/f22d01b/finder_test.go#L71-L73

Comment: Thanks a lot for example!

Comment: Of course, since the introduction of the `strings.Builder`, it can be actually used in favor of bytes.Buffer here.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Example is trivial:
```
var b strings.Builder;
html.Render(&b, node);
return b.String()
```
A rule of thumb:
if you need a buffer only for writing, and then extracting string at the end, use `strings.Builder`. If you need a buffer only for reading, initialized with a given string value, use `strings.Reader`. If you need a buffer for both reads and writes, use `bytes.Buffer`.